# On pop, the background is showing half vertical screen in black

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

My problem is on popup, the background is showing half vertical screen in black.

Need your help to fix this.

[image]

This is the code for popup

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupSearch7" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="d">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top">
        <h1>Search For</h1>
    </div>
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a> 
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom new-content">
        <input type="text" name="prodtitle" id="txtSearch7" value="" />
        <div align="center"><a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="flow" data-theme="g">Search</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone please help me out in identifying my mistake?
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Make a fiddle remaking this error :)

Comment: problem is this works perfectly fine on a computer. The problem comes only on mobile device. I tried it on two different devices and i found the same problem

Comment: Can anyone please help me out with this... the issue I am facing is specific to mobile devices. Any help will be highly appreciated. I am in desperate need of the solution

Comment: You need to provide more information, from an image there is not too much to tell :)